# Qual problem on the intersection of two surfaces

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

This is a qual problem that has been giving me some difficulty:

> Let
>   $$
>  \begin{align*}
>      f(x, y, z) &= x^2 + y^4 + z^6 - 3 \\
>      g(x, y, z) &= x + y + z,
>  \end{align*}
>  $$
>   and $S = \{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3\ \mid f(\vec{x}) = g(\vec{x}) = 0\}$.
>   Show that for every $\vec{v} \in S$ there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $\vec{v}$ such that:
>
> 1. There exists a differentiable, injective map $\gamma \colon (-\epsilon, \epsilon) \to U$.
> 2. $\gamma'$ does not vanish on $(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$.
> 3. The image of $\gamma$ is $U \cap S$.

This seems like a good problem for the implicit function theorem. I am fairly certain that the problem is solved if the Jacobian matrix

$$
J =
\begin{bmatrix}
   2x & 4y^3 & 6z^5 \\
    1 &  1   & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

has rank $2$ for all points in $S$. (In this case, we could choose two variables to solve in terms of the remaining third with the implicit function theorem.) However, the rank of $J$ does not seem easy to compute in $S$ (or anywhere else).

The rank of $J$ is $2$ precisely if a solution $(x, y, z) \in S$ cannot satisfy $2x = 4y^3 = 6z^5$. For this to work, we would want the equations
\begin{align*}
    2x = 4y^3 &= 6z^5 \\
    x^2 + y^4 + z^6 &= 3 \\
    x + y + z &= 0
\end{align*}
to have no solutions. Eliminating a variable with $x + y + z = 0$ doesn't seem immensely helpful. For example, substituting $z = -x - y$ gives $x^2 + y^4 + (x + y)^6 = 3$, which doesn't have any obviously nice properties.

Is there a better way to solve this question? If not, how should I proceed with the implicit function theorem?

Comment: Since we want $g(\vec{x})=0$ why not eliminate $z$?  Then we just have a relation between $x$ and $y$, which ought to be simpler.

Comment: @saulpatz You can do that, but you get an absolutely gnarly polynomial after subsequently eliminating either $x$ or $y$. Does the resulting expression have some nice property that rules out real roots?

Comment: I don't know.  That was just the first thing that occurred to me.  It helps if you describe the approaches you've rejected in your questions.

Comment: @saulspatz I've added a little more detail, thanks for the reminder. The gist of what I've added is that elimination of one variable via $x + y + z = 0$ doesn't seem immensely helpful given what results, unless it has some nice properties I haven't noticed.

Comment: Thanks.  I was trying implicit differentiation of $x^2 + y^4 + (x + y)^6 = 3$ but I couldn't get anywhere.

Comment: My answer uses transersality, but here is another idea: make the substitution $u=x+y+z,\ v=y,\ w=z$. Then the Jacobian determinant of this change of variables is non-zero and in these coordinates $S= \{(v+w)^2 + w^4 + w^6 - 3 =0;\ u=0\}$, which is easy to deal with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An idea: let $S' = \{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3\ \mid f(\vec{x})= 0\}$ and $S'' = \{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3\ \mid g(\vec{x})= 0\}.$ Then, $S=S'\cap S''.$ Fix $p=(x,y,z)\in S$.

Now, $\text{dim}T_pS'=3-\text{ker}f_*.$ But the Jacobian of $f_*$ is $\begin{pmatrix}
2x & 4y^3 & 6z^5
\end{pmatrix}$ so $\text{ker}f_*=1$ and so $\text{dim}T_pS'=2.$ Similarly, $\text{dim}T_pS''=2$ because the Jacobian of $g$ is $\begin{pmatrix}
1& 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$  from which it also follows that  $T_pS'\neq T_pS''.$

The upshot of this is that $S'$ and $S''$ intersect transversely and therefore $S'\cap S''=S$ is an embedded submanifold of $\mathbb R^3$ whose codimension is equal to the sum of the codimensions of $S'$ and $S''$, which is $2$. Therefore, $S$ is a curve in $\mathbb R^3$ and the rest of the exercise follows from this fact.

Comment: If I understand this correctly (my manifold knowledge is rusty), the difficulty I was having is solved by "$T_pS' \neq T_p S''$". How do we see that, given the Jacobians?

Comment: @rwbogl: The derivatives are, as you checked, linearly independent at $p$.